# How to reload page without losing any data

Tags: javascript, html, web, local-storage, reload

I am pretty new to web development and I am making this little project that consists in a little site that allows a user to add and remove their goals(kinda like a to do list)
I want to implement a last feature that allows the browser to save the content of the page, so that if the user reloads the page, he/she does not lose track of their goals. I tried using local storage but it's not working.

Any suggestion/tips on how to tackle such problem?
Thank you very much and I apologise, in advance for the code smell.

```js
var i = 0
 var j =0
 var parentElement = document.getElementById('new-goals')

 function addGoal(){
        var userGoal = window.prompt('Enter goal: ')
        var divTag = document.createElement('div')
        divTag.className = 'goalsSection'
        divTag.id = 'goal- ' + i
        i++
        var goal = document.createElement('p')
        goal.innerHTML = userGoal
        goal.className= 'usergoal'
        goal.id = 'UserGoal'+j
        

        var del = document.createElement('button')
        del.className = 'deleteButton'
        del.innerHTML = 'Delete Goal'
        del.id = j
        
        var com = document.createElement('button')
        com.className = 'completedButton'
        com.innerHTML = 'Not Completed'
        com.id = j
        j++

        
    
        com.onclick = function(e){

            if (com.innerHTML == 'Not Completed' ){
                var dec = window.prompt('Are you sure? this action can not be undo type y/n')
            if (dec == 'y'){
                com.innerHTML = 'Completed'
                var ele = e.target.id
                    var fin = 'UserGoal'+ele
                    document.getElementById(fin).style.textDecoration='line-through'
                
            }
    
         }

        }
        
       

        divTag.appendChild(goal)
        divTag.appendChild(del)
        divTag.appendChild(com)
        parentElement.appendChild(divTag)
        del.onclick = function(e){
            var id_toDelete = e.target.id
            var id_section = 'goal- ' + id_toDelete 
            alert(id_section)
            parentElement.removeChild(divTag)
        }
        

    }
```

```css
body{
  background-color: #003f5c;
}

h1{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 60px;
  font-family: 'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

.btnConatiner{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

#newGoalBtn{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 30px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  border: solid 5px black;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.goalsSection{
  border: solid 6px white;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 20px;
 background-color: white;
 margin: 10px;
 float: left;
}

.usergoal{
  text-align: center;
  font-size:20px;
}

.deleteButton{
  cursor: pointer;
}
.completedButton{
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
   
    <title>Goal Tracker</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Goal Tracker</h1>
<div class="btnConatiner">
    <button id="newGoalBtn" onclick="addGoal()">New Goal</button>
</div>
 <section class="add-goals">
<div id="new-goals">

</div>
 </section>
 <script src="app.js"></script>  
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thank you very much guys for the comments, I am starting to get the hang of it

Answer (score 1):

Inside the function **addGoal**, you can get all the goals that are already on the localstorage, and then push a new goal into the array and store.

```
// const goals = localStorage.getItem("goals") || []; // you can declare here too.
function addGoal() {
    const goals = localStorage.getItem("goals") || [];
    const userGoal = window.prompt("Enter goal:")
    goals.push(userGoal)
    localStorage.setItem('goals', JSON.stringify(goals)) // you need to transform into string
    ...
```

And then you can create a function to render the goals that are on the localstorage, like:

```
function renderGoals() {
    const goals = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("goals")); // parsing back
    // Then you can iterate on these goals (forEach for example) to render.
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use localStorage, but not to store all the HTML you're creating, rather to store the essential data. And from that data, you can easily rebuild your html.

First keep track of your data, and set up your addGoal function to accept an argument for the rebuilding (after page refresh)

```
let userGoals = [] // leave this empty for the moment
function addGoal(userGoal){
  if (!userGoal) { // this is a new one, so we'll store it in the array and localStorage
    userGoal = window.prompt('Enter goal: ')
    userGoals.push(userGoal);     
    localStorage.setItem('userGoals', JSON.stringify(userGoals)); // localStorage stores everything as strings so we stringify it
  } 
  //... the rest of this function
```

Then at the bottom of your script, create a `window.onload` function that runs once, when the page first loads. If there is data in `localStorage`, this will create your User Goals list

```
window.onload = function() { // this runs after the page has loaded
  if (localStorage.getItem('userGoals') ) { // if we have localStorage values waiting for us, parse them and iterate through them
    JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userGoals')).forEach(goal => {
       userGoals.push(goal)
       addGoal(goal)
     });
  }
}
```

...